# Sampling from a distribution function $g_{x}$ that will follow $f_{x}$

Tags: distributions, random-variable, markov-chain-montecarlo, random-generation

I am using acceptance-rejection sampling to sample random variable $x$ according to distribution $f(x)$. The steps I followed are

1. First generated uniformly distributed random variable $x$ from 0 to $x_{max}$
2. Generated a second random number $u$ between 0 and $f_{max}$.
3. Then checked the condition if $u < f(x)$, If this condition is satisfied then I accept $x$ otherwise reject and repeat the above two steps.

In the 1st step I have generated $x$ that follows a uniform distribution. Is it possible to sample random variable $x$ that already has distribution which is not uniform ? Means $x$ already has a distribution function $g(x)$ but I want to sample those $x$ who will follow my desired distribution function $f(x)$.

Example: The initial random variable $x$ has a distribution function as shown in the figure (which is not uniform).
[image]

My target distribution looks like the figure below.
[image]

Now Is it possible to sample $x$ from the first figure that will follow the target distribution function (second figure)? If yes, then how to do this? Should I use any other method than acceptance-rejection sampling.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can. For example, you can use the [independent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234767/convergence-of-the-independent-metropolis-hastings-algorithm) variant of the [Metropolis-Hasting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm).

1. Generate $x'$ from the distribution $g$,
2. Take

$$
x_{t+1} = \cases{
  x' \quad \text{with probability} \; \min\Big( \frac{f(x') g(x_t)}{f(x_t) g(x')}, \, 1\Big) \\
  x_t \quad \text{otherwise}
}
$$

See Christian P. Robert and George Casella *Monte Carlo Statistical Methods*, p. 276. Notice however that this would not work if $f$ and $g$ have different domains and would not be very efficient if the two distributions are very different from each other.

There may be even more efficient algorithms (see [mcmc](/questions/tagged/mcmc)) if you wouldn't insist on generating the samples independently from $g$.

Comment: Independent Metropolis is very close to accept-reject, with a higher average acceptance probability, but producing a dependent sequence. A slightly different approach is to use the [ratio of uniform method.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjmpry9-_T9AhWbTKQEHfTdDXsQFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1205.0482&usg=AOvVaw3urLxSTgDywACLps3V_IgF)